# How to dynamically set the height of a custom widget or set it to grow to fit content in AZURE DEVELOPER PORTAL

Tags: azure, apim

We have created a custom widget in the azure developer portal (managed). However if the widget displays no data, it contains a large amount of white space. If we set the height to inherit (and the parent section is also inherit) then it still displays a large block of white even when there is no content. As we display the widget above the USER:SUBSCRIPTIONS widget on the PROFILE page, this does not work as the USER:SUBSCRIPTIONS widget is pushed out of view to the user.

Is there a way to dynamically set the height of the widget depending on content, or alternatively to not display it and pull the subsequent content up if there is no content?

E.g. we are using the Vue template and have this..

```
<template>
  <div v-if="customPaidSubscriptions.length > 0" role="table" class="table">
```

So the template does not show any data, but still takes up a block on the page.

Many thanks for any help